# Store.subscribe: TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

I wanted to implement the Redux "subscribe" method to automatically save certain state changes to localstorage, as Dan Abramov explains in this video:
[Persisting the State to the Local Storage](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage)

I have done the same as in the video but I get the error:

```
TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function
```

And the project doesn't load. The error points to the `store.subscribe` function which I have in the store.js file. Can you see anyhing wrong here? Is anything in the wrong order or something?

Here is the store.js file (except the other imports):

```
import {throttle} from 'lodash/throttle';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const logger = createLogger({
    collapsed: true,
});

const middlewares = [
    sagaMiddleware,
    routerMiddleware(history),

]; 

const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
]; 

const composeEnhancers = 
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : compose;


const persistedState = loadState();

const store = createStore(
    reducers, 
    persistedState,
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
);

store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
    saveState({
        cart: store.getState().cart
    });
}), 1000);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

If I comment out "the store.subscribe" block, the error disappears

```
// store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
//  saveState({
//      cart: store.getState().cart
//  });
// }), 1000);
```

`Store.js` is imported in "`index.js`" and put in Provider:

```
 <Provider store={store}>
```

"`reducers`" (in the createStore method) is a file where all the reducers are combined (with combineReducers).

The "`localStorageHanding`" file I named differently than in Abramovs example , there was some conflict with files that import "localStorage" , I don't think localStorage needs to be imported however, but this isn't the issue anyway..).
The localStorageHandling's saveState and loadState functions are exactly as in the video:

```
export const loadState = () => {

    try{

        const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
        if(serializedState === null){
            return undefined;
        }

        return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    }catch(err){
        return undefined;
    }

}


    export const saveState = (state) => {

        try{
            const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
            localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);

        }catch(err){

        }
    }
```

I have

```
"react-redux": "^5.0.3", 
 "react": "^15.5.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should should either import `throttle` from the main entrypoint as a named import or as the default import from `lodash/throttle`

```
import { throttle } from 'lodash';

// or

import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';
```